# How to select a table entry which is a substring to a value

Tags: sql, db2

I have this problem:

I want to identify if a string within a table column is a substring of a given value.

This table (T_Prefix) includes a set of telephone number prefixes:

Prefix: 0175, 036840, 0162,...

And now I have the following phone number: 017512345789

My aim is to identify the prefix of this phone number. Therefore I want to start a sql Statement like this:

```
SELECT * from T_Prefix where prefix = LEFT(prefix,x_len);
```

The Problem is that I must reduce the length of the string.

Is there another opportunity?
Can I do this with help of a Stored Procedure?

Comment: so you want to see if a prefix exists on a certain record? i.e. You hand me a phone# and I tell you if it exists (yes|no) --OR-- return the actual prefix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can identify the prefix by doing:

```
select max(prefix)
from t_prefix p
where '017512345789' like concat(p.prefix, '%');
```

The `where` clause finds all matching prefixes.  The `max()` returns the longest one (because any two prefixes start with the same characters as in the shorter prefix, the max is the longest one).

Answer (score 0):

Another option might be

```
SELECT 
  PREFIX 
FROM
  T_PREFIX
WHERE
  LOCATE(PREFIX, '017512345789') = 1
```